# does @property update changed elements in an attribute or calculates it again?

Tags: python

I was wondering if using the `@property`  in python to update an attribute overwrites it or simply updates it? As the speed is very different in the 2 cases.
And in case it gets overwritten, what alternative can I use? Example:

```
class sudoku:
def __init__(self,puzzle):
    self.grid={(i,j):puzzle[i][j] for i in range(9) for j in range(9)}
    self.elements
    self.forbidden=set()

@property
def elements(self):
    self.rows=[[self.grid[(i,j)] for j in range(9)] for i in range(9)]
    self.columns=[[self.grid[(i,j)] for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
    self.squares={(i,j): [self.grid[(3*i+k,3*j+l)] for k in range(3) for l in range(3)] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)  } 
    self.stack=[self.grid]
    self.empty={k for k in self.grid.keys() if self.grid[k]==0}
```

Basically, I work with the `grid` method, and whenever I need to update the other attributes I call `elements`. I prefer to call it manually tho. The question, however, is that if I change `self.grid[(i,j)]`, does python calculate each attribute from scratch because `self.grid` was changed or does it only change the i-th row, j-th column etc?

Thank you

edit: added example code

Comment: I'm afraid your question makes no sense, at least the way you wrote it. Can you please provide a code example and explain what you mean by "update" and "overwrite" ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thank you. I hope my question is more understandable this way.

Comment: It is but alas I cannot answer it right now (I'm answering from my phone while commuting). But one thing I can tell you is that you're using properties in the wrongest way I've ever seen.

Comment: It's alright, take your time.
Is it? why so?

Comment: cf my edited answer. I'm afraid you won't like it though - bad news, Python has no mind-reading abilities and wrapping a function in a `property` doesn't make it any more "magic".

Comment: That makes things a lot clearer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, your question is totally unclear - but anyway, since you don't seem to understand what a `property` is and how it works...

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x / 2

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value * 2
```

Here we have a class with a get/set ("binding") property `x`, backed by a protected attribute `_x`.

The "@property" syntax here is mainly syntactic sugar, you could actually write this code as

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_x(self):
        return self._x / 2

    def set_x(self, value):
        self._x = value * 2

    x = property(fget=get_x, fset=set_x)
```

The only difference with the previous version being that the `get_x` and `set_x` functions remain available as methods. Then if we have an `obj` instance:

```
obj = Obj(2, 4)
```

Then

```
x = obj.x
```

is just a shortcut for

```
x = obj.get_x()
```

and

```
obj.x = 42
```

is just a shortcut for

```
obj.set_x(42)
```

How this "shortcut" works is [fully documented here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), with [a whole chapter dedicated to the `property` type](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties).

As you can see there's nothing magical here, and once you get (no pun intended) the descriptor protocol and how the `property` class uses it, you can answer the question by yourself.

Note that properties will ALWAYS add some overhead (vs plain attributes or direct method call) since you have more indirections levels and method calls invoked, so it's best to only use them when it really makes sense.

EDIT: now you posted your code, I confirm that you don't understand Python's "properties" - not only the technical side of it but even the basic concept of a "computed attribute".

The point of computed attributes in general (the builtin `property` type being just one generic implementation of) is to have the interface of a plain attribute (something you can get the value if with `value = obj.attrname` and eventually set the value of with `obj.attrname = somevalue`) but actually invoking a getter (and eventually a setter) behind the hood.

Your `elements` "property" while technically implemented as a read-only property, is really a method that initializes half a dozen attributes of your class, doesn't return anything (well it implicitely returns `None`) and which return value is actually never used (of course). *This is definitly not what computed attributes are for*. This should NOT be a property, it should be a plain function (with some explicit name such as "setup_elements" or whatever makes sense here).

```
# nb1 : classes names should be CamelCased
# nb2 : in Python 2x, you want to inherit from 'object'

class Sudoku(object):
    def __init__(self,puzzle):
        self.grid={(i,j):puzzle[i][j] for i in range(9) for j in range(9)}
        self.setup_elements()
        self.forbidden=set()

    def setup_elements(self):
        self.rows=[[self.grid[(i,j)] for j in range(9)] for i in range(9)]
        self.columns=[[self.grid[(i,j)] for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
        self.squares={(i,j): [self.grid[(3*i+k,3*j+l)] for k in range(3) for l in range(3)] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)  } 
        self.stack=[self.grid]
        self.empty={k for k, v in self.grid.items() if v==0}
```

Now to answer your question:

> if I change self.grid[(i,j)], does python calculate each attribute from scratch because self.grid was changed

`self.grid` is a plain attribute, so just rebinding `self.grid[(i, j)]` doesn't make "python" calculate anything else, of course. None of your object's other attributes will be impacted. Actually Python (the interpreter) has no mind-reading ability and will only do *exactly* what you asked for, nothing less, nothing more, period.

> or does it only change the i-th row, j-th column

This :

```
obj = Sudoku(some_puzzle)
obj.grid[(1, 1)] = "WTF did you expect ?"
```

will NOT (I repeat: "**NOT**") do **anything** else than assigning the literal string `"WTF did you expect ?"` to `obj.grid[(1, 1)]`. **None** of the other attributes will be updated in any way.

Now if your question was: "if I change something to `self.grid` *and* call `self.setup_elements()` after, will Python recompute all attributes or only update `self.rows[xxx]` and  `self.columns[yyy]`", then the answer is plain simple: Python will do **exactly** what you asked for: it will execute `self.setup_elements()`, line after line, statement after statement. Plain and simple. No magic here, and the **only** thing you'll get from making it a `property` instead of a plain method is that you won't have to type the `()` after to invoke the method.

So if what you expected from making this `elements()` method a property was to have some impossible magic happening behind the scene to detect that you actually only wanted to recompute impacted elements, then bad news, this is not going to happen, and you will have to *explicitely* tell the interpreter how to do so. Computed attributes *might* be part of the solution here, but not by any magic - you will have to write all the code needed to intercept assignments to any of those attributes and recompute what needs to be recomputed.

Beware, since all those attributes are mutable containers, just wrapping each of them into properties won't be enough - consider this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = {"a":1, "b": 2}
    @property
    def bar(self):
        print("getting self._bar")
        return self._bar
    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        print("setting self._bar to {}".format(value))
        self._bar = value

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar
getting self._bar
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> f.bar['z'] = "WTF ?"
getting self._bar
>>> f.bar
getting self._bar
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'z': 'WTF ?'}
>>> bar = f.bar
getting self._bar
>>> bar
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'z': 'WTF ?'}
>>> bar["a"] = 99
>>> f.bar
getting self._bar
{'a': 99, 'b': 2, 'z': 'WTF ?'}
```

As you can see, we could mutate `self._bar` without the `bar.setter` function ever being invoked - because `f.bar["x"] = "y"` is actually NOT assigning to `f.bar` (which would need `f.bar = "something else") but _getting_ the`f._bar`dict thru the`Foo.bar`getter, then invoking`**setitem**()` on this dict.

So if you want to intercept something like `f.bar["x"] = "y"`, you will also have to write some dict-like object that will intercept all mutators access on the dict itself ( `__setitem__`, but also `__delitem__` etc) and notify `f` of those changes, and change your property so that it returns an instance of this dict-like objects instead.